# Which is the best way for drawing graphics items with QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, collision-detection, qt-quick

In my QML application I need common QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsObject possibilities like detect collision, "movable" and "selectable" flags, drag-and-drop etc. Should I inherit my classes from QQuickItem or use QML Canvas? Sure I'd like to write less code and choose a "QML-way".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For collision detection in QML you can use Box 2D QML plug-in. It has lots of good features and could be downloaded from [here](https://gitorious.org/qml-box2d).

You can also implement collision detection on your own. For example by checking this :

```
Math.sqrt((ball1.x-ball2.x)*(ball1.x-ball2.x)+(ball1.y-ball2.y)*(ball1.y-ball2.y))<epsilon
```

For making a QML item movable you can do something like :

```
Image {
    id: icon
    width: 64
    height: 64
    source: "liverbird.gif"

    MouseArea {
        id: liverbirdMouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent

        property variant iconObj
        property int startX
        property int startY

        onPressed: {
            startX = mouseX
            startY = mouseY
            var iconComp = Qt.createComponent("icon.qml");
            iconObj = iconComp.createObject(parent);
            iconObj.x = mouseX - iconObj.width/2
            iconObj.y = mouseY - iconObj.height/2
        }
        onPositionChanged: {
            iconObj.x += mouseX - startX
            iconObj.y += mouseY - startY
            startX = mouseX
            startY = mouseY
        }
        onReleased: {
            iconObj.destroy()
        }
    }
}
```